# Xml Rss feed parser trouble in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xml-parsing, rss

i am really new to Xcode, but here i followed this tutorial [HERE](http://www.codeliscious.com/?p=784), and even downloaded the project and tried to implement it into mine, but for some reason, i can not get it to work. I have no errors or anything. Also, my table is connected already, so i do not know what the problem is. Here is some of my code:

ViewController.h

```
    @interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView * newsTable;
    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator;
    CGSize cellSize;
    NSXMLParser * rssParser;
    NSMutableArray * stories;

    // a temporary item; added to the "stories" array one at a time, and cleared for the next one
    NSMutableDictionary * item;

    // it parses through the document, from top to bottom...
    // we collect and cache each sub-element value, and then save each item to our array.
    // we use these to track each current item, until it's ready to be added to the "stories" array
    NSString * currentElement;
    NSMutableString * currentTitle, * currentDate, * currentSummary, * currentLink;
}
- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
    @implementation ThirdViewController


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [stories count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    }

    // Set up the cell
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    cell.textLabel.text=[[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic

    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

    NSString * storyLink = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"link"];
    NSLog(@"%@",stories );
    // clean up the link - get rid of spaces, returns, and tabs...
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    storyLink = [storyLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@""];

    // open in Safari
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if ([stories count] == 0) {
        NSString * path = @"http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog";
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }
    cellSize = CGSizeMake([newsTable bounds].size.width, 60);
}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");
}

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //you must then convert the path to a proper NSURL or it won't work
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    // here, for some reason you have to use NSClassFromString when trying to alloc NSXMLParser, otherwise you will get an object not found error
    // this may be necessary only for the toolchain
    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
    [rssParser setDelegate: self];

    // Depending on the XML document you're parsing, you may want to enable these features of NSXMLParser.
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [rssParser parse];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);
    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    NSLog(@"all done!");
    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
    [newsTable reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved this via chats and junk. :-)

Turns out the delegate and dataSource weren't set, so the table view wasn't populating.